# Remove soffit / refrofit attic rafter baffle vent

Tags: attic, soffit

Will I be able to pry down this soffit venting/siding to secure baffle/rafter vents (I understand you really want to secure down that leading edge so you don't have creeping underneath and hitting the insulation insulation?)

There are some flimsy vents up in the attic now but they are not the full width of the rafters and not snug, just sorta laying there. Was looking at a more rigid product like accuvent, dci smart baffle, etc.

Don't mind that gap on the corner, I know we have bats right now.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a bat exclusion in this very spot at the moment. Going to have to do it from the inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend it. You'd have to undo the fascia at least partway (and remove the gutter, where applicable) to drop the outer ends of each panel. This means pulling nails carefully so as not to dent the metal, removing the fascia, then pulling nails or staples from the soffit panels (into the subfascia). You'll want to precisely align every nail hole on re-installation to avoid problems at the end of each section.

It's not difficult for a patient person, but it's time consuming and putzy. If that's not you, expect to have dented and bent up metal before you're done.

You might be better off doing the attic belly crawl unless there's some reason you can't.